# Busqueda mediante dos inputs en el mismo form

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta multiple, usando dos `inputs` en un solo `form` pero al momento en que doy enter me trae todo de la base de datos sin importer el tipo del `que buscas?`o el `en donde?`.

El codigo de mi busqueda es este:

```
<?php session_start();

require 'extras/config.php';
require 'functions.php';

comprobarSession();

$conexion = conexion($bd_config);
if (!$conexion) {
    header('Location: error.php');
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && !empty($_GET['busqueda']) || !empty($_GET['busqueda2'])) {
    $busqueda = limpiarDatos($_GET['busqueda']);
    $busqueda2 = limpiarDatos($_GET['busqueda2']);

    $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM publications WHERE titulo LIKE :busqueda or locacion LIKE :busqueda2');

    $statement->execute(array(':busqueda' => "%$busqueda%", ':busqueda2' => "%$busqueda2%"));
    $resultados = $statement->fetchAll();

    if(empty($resultados)){
        $titulo = 'No se encontraron articulos con el resultado ';
    } else {
        $titulo = 'Resultados de la busqueda: ';
    }
}

require 'views/buscar.php';

?>
```

y este es mi form:

```
<form class="form-search-home" name="busqueda" method="GET" action="<?php echo RUTA; ?>indexsearch.php">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>¿Que buscas?</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control  input-lg" placeholder="Palabras clave" name="busqueda">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>¿En donde?</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Lugar" name="busqueda2">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-t-primary btn-lg btn-theme btn-pill btn-block">Buscar</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <a href="#modal-advanced" data-toggle="modal">Encuentra el trabajo que quieres!</a>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

y este es el resultado que trae por la URL

> http://localhost/talvez%20usuarioindexsearch.php?busqueda=diseno&busqueda2=saltillo

Comment: podrias colocar el error que te sale

Comment: No me marca ningun error, el problema es que aunque le pongas solo el tipo, el lugar o ambos, no los respeta y trae todo de la base de datos

Comment: coloca la tabla en un simple txt la consulta que te arroja el php y el resultado; PHP y MySql cuando envias MAYUSCULAS y minuscula no la respeta

Comment: @JackNavaRow con lo de "no los respeta", me refiero a que por decir, coloco en el imput de busqueda 2, un estado de mexico, no lo toma en cuenta y solo trae todo lo que hay en la case de datos, de igual manera con el input de ¿que buscas? o con ambos, no se si me di a entender mas claramente

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el bind_param

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare();

$statement= $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM publications WHERE (titulo LIKE ?) or (locacion LIKE ?)');
$statement->bind_param("ss", $busqueda, $busqueda2);
$statement->execute();
$resultados = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Bueno ya pude seleccionar el error, el error fue que en la parte del `form` en el `action` lo tenia de la siguiente manera `action="<?php echo RUTA; ?>indexsearch.php"` me hacia falta la barra. aunque ahora el siguiente problema es que no toma las dos variables, solo la de la primera

Comment: Prueba a meter un print_r[$_GET] para ver que datos te están llegando al indexsearch.php

Comment: lo realice y si imprime las dos variables

Comment: pero sigue sin traer los resultados correctos, trae toda la informacionde la bd

Comment: Prueba con: `$statement->execute(array(':busqueda' => "%".$busqueda."%", ':busqueda2' => "%".$busqueda2."%"));`

Comment: sigue trayendome todos los resultados, no hace una consulta concreta, coloco cualquiera de los dos inputs y no respeta las variables

Comment: He modificado la respuesta. Mira a ver si con otra función funciona mejor. Revisa que locacion es un campo de la tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te recomiendo esque lo captures con POST de esa forma te aseguras que lso datos no esten vacios, te dejo un fragmento del codigo que te podria servir.

```
$buscas = $_POST[Busqueda];
$lugar =$_POST[Busqueda2];

    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM publications WHERE titulo LIKE '%$buscas%' or locacion LIKE '%$lugar%'");
    $resultados = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Detalla más tu respuesta, recuerda que no solo le estas respondiendo al OP, sino a futuros usuarios que pueden tener un problema muy similar

Comment: Los campos POST también pueden estar vacios. Y tu código está expuesto a una Inyección de SQL.